# Send Google Assistant text to read out via the SDK

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I want to write an app that will relay information about public transport via the Google Assistant if prompted.

Does the Google Assistant SDK allow an app to send text to be read out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Google Assistant supports [Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/) which allow developers to respond to requests from users. Actions can only respond if prompted, **they cannot speak unannounced** at this time.

Using the Actions SDK, you must first [define some actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/define-actions):

```js
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "MAIN",
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
      },
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "demoApp"
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "demoApp": {
      "name": "demoApp",
      "url": "https://example.com/demoApp"
    }
  }
}
```

This would use the *fulfillment* `demoApp` to respond to the command 'Ok Google, talk to [action name]'. This essentially amounts to a request to the specified URL.

You then need to [write some server code](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/fulfillment) to handle these requests. Google provide a library for [Node.js](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) which might be helpful. I'm just going to quote
the example code there as it's sufficiently clear and helpful to point you
in the right direction.

```js
'use strict';

const ActionsSdkApp = require('actions-on-google').ActionsSdkApp;

exports.<insertCloudFunctionName> = (req, res) => {
  const app = new ActionsSdkApp({request: req, response: res});

  function mainIntent (app) {
    // Put your message here, using app.tell.
    app.tell('Hello, world!');
  }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.MAIN, mainIntent);
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
}
```

You then just need to [deploy](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/deploy-fulfillment) and [submit](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/submit-app) your app. You would need to put your logic to determine what text to say inside
of `mainIntent`, or create new intents as necessary.

Comment: "they cannot speak unannounced at this time"
Could you use the "broadcast" command?

Comment: @firedude144 Not really — the way that Actions are currently used makes  this impossible. Your action can only communicate with the Google Assistant if Google's servers make a request to your action, and they'll only do that if asked to do so by voice command. I wouldn't be surprised if this comes in future, but it won't work yet.